# How do I name an object in the Business Layer that only does work?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, business-logic

I've looked around and haven't found anything specific to my question but that's partially because I'm unsure how to phrase it.

I manage around 20 different C# .NET applications that all do relatively similar things.

I am working on consolidating the common code into a data, business logic, and presentation.

My question is related to the Business Logic layer.

I gather that a business/domain object is one that holds state and sometimes may perform related actions (if you take that approach).

But what would you call an object that is only working through a routine?

For example:

1. In the presentation layer a button event is fired.
2. The presentation layer points to this class and calls the "RunJob()"
   method.
3. RunJob() does all the work it needs to do and then finishes.  For
       example, it may read a table and output it into a CSV (a lot of
       these apps are data pushers).  It may or may not use internal
       fields/properties.  These properties may be used to display data in
       the interface or to create output.

Is there a name for this or is it just a bad pattern/bad OO in practice?  I don't think this qualifies as a business object or helper.  I've seen some [other topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928325/what-is-the-definition-of-a-service-object) that hint it might be a "Service" object.

Thanks!

Comment: Just FYI:  I believe a "Sevice" class is what I was going for here.  This convention works for me.

Comment: Just to add... I've taken to place these things in a "Service" layer but typically these things are named a lot better than I was suggesting.  RunJob is a terrible name and suggests some bad design (code smell).  Then again I asked this in 2012...

Answer (score 0):

call it WorkerThread for now and see uncle bob's article on naming" http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/Naming.pdf. then change the name to something reasonable.

your class is not necessarily a bad class. most entities usually do not have much behaviour, otoh some helper classes do not have much state.

Answer (score 0):

The name of your objects depend on specifically what work they do.  TableImporter and CsvExporter are good names for the tasks you described.  The methods should also be appropriately named.  It may be the case that you want to abstract an interface `Runner` and have a generic `RunJob` method to decouple your presentation and model layers, but it could be more clear and decoupled if you use a controller instead.